# Ratio of Odds Ratios?

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, odds-ratio

How would one compute the ratio of odds ratios for unlinked (but theoretically overlapping samples)? I basically have one dataset that can be considered my "population" or "universe" of data, and another one (newspaper coverage) that should theoretically overlap with the previous dataset, but probably won't due to bias in reporting.

So for instance, if I get an exp(B) of 1.24 for black vs white kids killed by handguns in my logistic regression of one dataset, but an exp(B) of 0.45 for the reporting of black vs white kids killed by handguns in my other data set, and I want to compute the ratio of odd ratios, can I simply say 0.45/1.24 = 0.36?

What about the confidence intervals? And how exactly should I interpret that figure (0.36) (i.e. does it mean the media under-reports 64% of black child-victim murder?)

Comment: Why not compute an odds ratio of black/white victim vs. black/white reported? Your two odds ratios are from two models that predict two different outcomes, I'm not sure how that division would make sense.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight- the larger dataset has been coded on a case-by-case basis (given to us as such). I can't link the crimes covered in the newspaper articles to this larger database on a case-by-case basis unfortunately because it would be difficult to match, given the absence of identifying information in the newspapers. Hence I have two datasets. I'm not sure if I understood your suggestion correctly though?